# Bluescreen after Ubuntu 12.10 installation, after recommended boot repair "no filesystem found" please help!

Tags: windows, windows-7, bootloader, boot-repair, testdisk

After I tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 into my Windows 7 a black screen came up and nothing happened for over five minutes. So I force shutdown my computer and started again on the linux CD. I partitioned the Linux partitions manually and installed Ubuntu. At the next reboot I got a bluescreen from Windows three secounds after loading.

I tried to repair the problem by using boot-repair.
Then I got out the url: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1430803
And after the next restart he told me that he didn't found the filesystem.
Because he didn't found the filesystem it was unable to repair it with the windows CD.

Then I tried to repair it with TestDisk and was able to change the Windows Partition into NTFS, but I was not able to repair the windows 7 boot partition.

Now I get the message that No Bootloader is found when I restart.

Please help me.

Comment: Now I tried again to repair it over boot-repair and created a generic MDR which points to my Windows partition with the system and all my data. It still doesn't work.

But I've got a new link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1435621/

Comment: Did you back up your data on Windows before you started installing Ubuntu? If not then I would strongly advise you to do so now before attempting any more repairs. You should start up the Ubuntu Live CD by choosing "Try Ubuntu" from the installer and copy all the important files from your Windows partition onto some external drive.

Comment: I backed up the most necessairy files. If I would have to completly re-instal my computer, it wouldn't be doomsday, but I would have some trouble getting my Windows back in a reasonable time because I don't have a Installation CD only a HP Restore partition which is broken now.

Answer (score 0):

1. download and use a Windows disc this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader , until you get direct access to Windows
2. then use Boot-Repair to recover the GRUB menu